# How to ignore object property when comparing arrays of objects in Vitest?

Tags: javascript, testing, vitest

I would like to write a test for my function, but it generates unique ids for each call.

The problem is that the data structure is a tree, so objects might be endlessly nested and I can't just `delete expect.id` and `delete result.id`. However, obviously enough, I could write a recursive helper function for this, but I am wondering if there is another way for this.

This is the simple example of what I want:

```
const expect = [
    {
        id: 'id-1',
        data: [
            {
                id: 'id-2',
                data: 'Some data'
            }
        ]
    }
]

const result = [
    {
        id: 'id-3',
        data: [
            {
                id: 'id-4',
                data: 'Some data'
            }
        ]
    }
]

expect(result).toEqual(expect) // will be false due to different ids
```

Comment: what fields are you trying to test? maybe just write individual expects for each field that you want to test